# Instance Normalization Error while converting model from tensorflow to Coreml (4.0)

Tags: tensorflow, normalization, coreml, coremltools

I try to convert my model from Tensorflow to Coreml however I get below error. Isn't it possible to convert instance normalization layer to CoreML? Any workaround to overcome?

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
6
7 model = ct.convert(
----> 8     tf_keras_model )

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/mil/block.py in remove_ops(self, existing_ops)
700                         + "used by ops {}"
701                     )
--> 702                     raise ValueError(msg.format(op.name, i, v.name, child_op_names))
703                 # Check that the output Var isn't block's output
704                 if v in self._outputs:

ValueError: Cannot delete op 'Generator/StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/encoder_down_resblock_0/instance_norm_0/Shape' with active output at id 0: 'Generator/StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/encoder_down_resblock_0/instance_norm_0/Shape' used by ops ['Generator/StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/encoder_down_resblock_0/instance_norm_0/strided_slice']
SEARCH STACK OVERFLOW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use keras-contrib instead and it works fine. Please see issue and its solution below. It is still open for  tensorflow_addons.

https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/1007